# Feature Engineering: Scaling for different distributions

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I am trying to understand the best way to scale my features and learn how to use SciKit package to transform/fit on my predicting dataset.

I have 2 groups of data.

First group has normal distribution, so I am just looking to scale the values (positive values between 20-100) using minmax scaler.

Second group of features has outliers so I believe the robustscaler will give better results.

My question is

1. Can I use multiple scalers on my dataset for a classification problem using RF?
2. Within SciKit, when I try to scale just 1 feature using robustscaler on my training data, I am getting this error. **ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:**  I am not sure how to read this error, can I not scale just one feature?
3. If I using two scalers for my data, what is the best way to implement the feature engineering if I am looking to make predictions one row at a time? Do I just use transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you can if you find it useful.
2. You can scale single feature.
   If you do something like this you will have an error:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "feature1": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "feature2": [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
    "feature3": [200, 300, 400, 500, 600],
})

scaler = StandardScaler()

scaler.fit_transform(df["feature1"])

# output
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
```

You need to additionally reshape input if this is single column:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()

scaler.fit_transform(df["feature1"].values.reshape(-1, 1))

# output
array([[-1.41421356],
       [-0.70710678],
       [ 0.        ],
       [ 0.70710678],
       [ 1.41421356]])
```

3. You can branch preprocessing using ColumnTransformer.

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "feature1": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "feature2": [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
    "feature3": [200, 300, 400, 500, 600],
})

transformers = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("scaling1", MinMaxScaler(), ["feature1"]),
        ("scaling2", StandardScaler(), ["feature2", "feature3"])
    ]
)

transformed_df = transformers.fit_transform(df)

transformed

# output
array([[ 0.        , -1.41421356, -1.41421356],
       [ 0.25      , -0.70710678, -0.70710678],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.75      ,  0.70710678,  0.70710678],
       [ 1.        ,  1.41421356,  1.41421356]])
```

If you would like to for example use first scaler (scaling1) to inverse transform:

```
scaler_1 = transformers.named_transformers_["scaling1"]
scaler_1.inverse_transform(transformed[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1))

# output
array([[1.],
       [2.],
       [3.],
       [4.],
       [5.]])
```

Comment: I don't think I get the ColumnTransformer part. If I scaled my features for my training dataset, when I am looking to make predictions on my live data (one row at a time) shouldn't I be using the mean/variance from my training dataset to scale the features?

Comment: Yes it should. That's why you should run `transformers.fit_transform()` on training data. 
After that `transformers` will keep mean/std of training set and next you will apply that on testing set with command `transformers.transform()` - it will apply those mean/std learned on training set but this time on testing set. Just you need to run `transform` method instead of `fit` or `fit_transform`.